# SqlDependency OnChange not firing when events happen

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, signalr, sqldependency

I know there is a similar question on SO that has an answer, and after reading that and other articles, I'm still not sure why I can't get this wired up properly. I've tried quite a bit of examples and have been trying different things and simply can't get it to work. I know there are refactoring opportunities but I'm trying to keep it simple right now just to get it working first.

I have permissions to the db, and I can see that a temporary service and queue gets created. One thing I noticed though was that if I run a query, the queue does not display any records and my `dependency_OnChange` event does not get fired. I'm assuming it's not getting fired because nothing is entering the queue...

**UPDATE:** I'm getting it to fire now, however, the only event I get is `Subscribe`. The `SqlNotificationEventArgs` show `Invalid` for the `Info`, but my query and table match all the `SELECT` rules for sql dependency.

**Global.asax:**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    SqlDependency.Start(_entityConnString);
}

protected void Application_End()
{
    SqlDependency.Stop(_entityConnString);
}
```

**InfectionPreventionHub.cs:** *(This is a simple SignalR Hub that starts up with a certain area)*

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sends the notifications.
    /// </summary>
    [HubMethodName("sendUpdates")]
    private void SendUpdates()
    {
        var infectionPreventionItems = InfectionPreventionOperations.GetInfectionPrevention();

        var vm = new InfectionPreventionViewModel
        {
            InfectionPrevention = infectionPreventionItems
        };

        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm);

        GetUpdates();

        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<InfectionPreventionHub>();
        context.Clients.All.RecieveUpdates(result);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the updates.
    /// </summary>
    private void GetUpdates()
    {
        const string commandText = @"SELECT [Id], [FirstName] FROM [TestDb].[dbo].[Association]";

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(EntityConnString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
            {
                command.Notification = null;

                var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(sqlDependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                // NOTE: You have to execute the command, or the notification will never fire.
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the OnChange event of the sqlDependency control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="SqlNotificationEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void sqlDependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Check for the type of event
        GetUpdates();
        SendUpdates();
    }
```

It was real easy to wire this up to RavenDB, but SqlServer is giving me a hard time.

`GetUpdates` only fires once when the hub connection happens, which I thought would start up the dependency. However, when updating or adding something to the `Association` table, no events get raised. I'm required to use `SignalR` for the UI's realtime updates and data will be entered via 3rd party tools. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what controls did you used on that on changed event

Comment: @reds I'm not sure I understand the question...